# SharePoint 2013 Power pivot in excel no found

Tags: powerpivot, sql-server-2008

I have a 
Sharepoint2013 (Enterprice) with excel services installed and power pivot with SQL SERVER 2012 R2 (Enterprice).
In another physical server i have a SQL Server 2008 (Enterprice) and i have 14 OLAP Cubes, when i use Excel desktop i can connect to sql server Via power pivot but when i upload my excel to sharepoint and i try refresh conections i recive this error:

[image]

Error: 
An error occurred while working with the data model in the workbook. Retry.

You can not update one or more data connections in the workbook.
Could not update connections:

SqlServer datos5 Logistica

Srry by my poor english.

Comment: Please paste your error message as a text translated by google :) to can know which error you got!

Comment: @M.Qassas is done

Comment: Great job , please add your answer to be useful for future visitors